# how to use Copulae in Python

Tags: python, distribution, data-augmentation

I'm using Copulae package, following the example of https://github.com/DanielBok/copulae.
My understanding is that the simulated values should have similar distribution as the input ones.

I would like to see the output dataframe of the fit (that is: the simulated data), and check its distribution. However, "fitted" produced below is not an array or df that I can open.
How can I extract the fitted data?

```
from copulae import NormalCopula
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(8)
data = np.random.normal(size=(300, 8))
plt.hist(data[:,1],    bins=100) #checking input data histogram
cop = NormalCopula(8)
cop.fit(data)  #fitting data with copula
fitted=cop.fit(data)
```

Comment: in your link you can find link to documentation - maybe you should read it - ie. [example](https://copulae.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/usage_guide.html)

Comment: @furas: unhelpfull comment, I did read and that's why I'm asking. Thanks.

Comment: it is only comment, not solution, and it doesn't have to be helpful. But I wrote this comment becaus every day many, many people ask question before reading documentation and before using Google to find solution.